# Parallel/Multithreaded reading from ByteBuffer/Netty ByteBuff

Tags: java, multithreading, buffer, netty, nio

Heyho,

**ByteBuffers** as well as netty's **ByteBuff** use indices to store where they currently "are". At the start of my application I **load** multiple files in **ByteBuffers/ByteBuffs** to read later from those. Also the bytebuffers are **immutable** after loading. My problem is now that **multiple clients** should be able to **read** from those byte buffers, but because they use the **same** reader/writer indices it won't work. Is there a easy way of maintaining the indices maybe **per thread**? Does netty have some "tools" to achive this?

I've already read that nio ByteBuffers do not support multiple threads, but is this also true if you **only read** from them?

Basically I'm only looking for a way to send data, which is stored in memory, very fast over netty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call duplicate on the ByteBuf for every new Thread and use the returned ByteBuf. Those will share the same content but not the same indices.

```
ByteBuf duplicate = ByteBuf.duplicate();
```

Comment: For my netty buffers I could use Allocator.wrappedBuffer(...) to fix the indices. So reading from multiple threads should be safe, right?

Comment: As long as you use get*() and not read*() yes, as read*() will increase the readerIndex.